# uWSGI: Using emperor mode, register internal routing rules for vassals

Tags: python, uwsgi, microservices

I am using uWSGI to deploy python wsgi microservices.

My architecture looks like :

- Emperor => handles routing of all request starting by /api
- Vassal "users" => handles request on /api/users
- Vassal "payments" => handles request on /api/payments
- etc.

The routing is handled by the emperor using internal routing rules.

My problem is that routing rules are statically defined in the emperor configuration file.

1/ Is there any way for a vassal to "dynamically" (= on startup) add rules to the emperor internal routing table ?

2/ If not, is there any way for an emperor to "get" routing rules from the vassal when starting it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emperor's purpose is managing processes (vassals), the 'routing' concept is the job of 'corerouters' (fastrouter, httprouter, sslrouter, rawrouter). For your case the subscription system could be the best solution:

http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/SubscriptionServer.html

in 2.1 (current github master) there is the possibility to subscribe 'by mountpoint'

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems that the subscribe 'by mountpoint' feature will fit some of my needs.

Comment: (sorry for splitting my comment in two parts by accident)
Thanks for your answer. It seems that the subscribe 'by mountpoint' feature will fit some of my needs.

But, if I have to handle more complex cases like routing using some random header argument or using the query_string, I think the subscription mechanism won't allow me to do that.

If I create my own subscription mechanism, is there any way to dynamically add/remove rules in the internal routing table ?

Comment: yes, check this example: https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/blob/master/contrib/subscribe.pl you can create custom subscription packets from external processes